# Recordset to Dataset conversion

Tags: c#, vb6, dataset, recordset

I am converting `VB6` code to `C#` so far the conversion goes fine but I was just confused with `Recordset` conversion to `Dataset` so far I converted and assigned the recordset data using dataset as follows

```
String strData = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Col"].ToString(); 
//this is in VB6 code rs!Col
```

Is this conversion correct, if so I am having some recordset as follows

```
double d = rs(somestring).Value // before this a select query executed
```

How can I convert this using `dataset`

```
double d= double.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["someString"].ToString());
```

Also `rs.Fields(col)`

Is it correct or any other?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:-

```
ADODB.Connection oConn = new ADODB.Connection();
oConn.Open("Connection String", "", "", 0);
string strQuery = "";//Your select query or the query through which you are fetching data from database";
ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
rs.Open(strQuery, " Connection String,                ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, 1);
adapter.Fill(dt, rs);
return dt;
```

Comment: CHeck this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409385/convert-persisted-ado-2-8-com-recordset-to-ado-net-dataset

Answer (score 0):

The near most object to recordset in ado.net is reader. Reader opens a forward only read only cursor and allows you to read the records. There is a basic difference between recordset and dataset.

Dataset is in-memory full copy of queried data. Once you fetch data in dataset, it does not require the connection whereas the recordset requires the connection. If you do not want to move forward and backward through your results, you should try reader. You will be able to use similar syntax to fetch data from reader.

Comment: Hi I need conversion and is that code correct as per converted

Comment: Yes it is correct. However, you can optimize it by directly using toDouble, toInt or toString methods. Further, you can also fetch data in table instead of dataset which will allow you a to write a code like tables.rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();